# node js saving all values as 0 in sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, rest, express

Im making an API on nodejs with express and mysql. In the POST method i dont get any error but on mysql store al values as 0, like this:

```
1
0
0.00
0000-00-00
0
```

(the 1 is the ID autoincremental)

To test the post method im using POSTMAN like this:

```
{
    "Id" : null,
    "Concepto" : "Desde POSTMAN",
    "Monto" : 10,
    "Fecha" : "1988-05-05",
    "Tipo" : "Ingreso"
}
```

and this is the function

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { id,concepto,monto,fecha,tipo } = req.body; 
    mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO operaciones (Id, Concepto, Monto, fecha, Tipo) VALUES (?)", [req.body],(err, rows, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json({Status: "Operacion Saved"});
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
});
```

Any advice, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your table definition I assume that the DB engine is defaulting to the `0` values you're getting as the query is passing empty values.

You should be using `?` placeholders for each input you'd like to pass to the query.
Also, the deconstructed values aren't actually used.

Please try the following code:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { id, Concepto, Monto, Fecha, Tipo } = req.body;
    mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO operaciones (Concepto, Monto, Fecha, Tipo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", [Concepto, Monto, Fecha, Tipo], (err, results, fields) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.json({ Status: "Operacion Saved" });
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
    });
});
```

Notice `id` isn't used in the query as you've mentioned it's set as auto-increment.